# JavaFX Text Pastes on Top of Itself

Tags: java, javafx

I am having a problem with the Text object in my JavaFX game pasting over itself and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  My Text object keeps pasting over itself despite me removing it before I add the new one.  I believe the error should be in my method setTextField, but I'm including the code for my entire GamePane Class below that just in case it's helpful.  Thank you in advance for any and all help & advice!  :)

Just my setTextField method:

```
public void setTextField() {
    Text showScore = new Text("Score:  " +     String.valueOf(playerPointCounter)
        + "\nMisses:  " + String.valueOf(gameOverCounter));
    showScore.setLayoutX(25);
    showScore.setLayoutY(35);
    showScore.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    //Font family, weight, font size
    showScore.setFont(Font.font("Baskerville Old Face", FontWeight.BOLD,     20));
    this.getChildren().remove(showScore);
    this.getChildren().add(showScore);
} //End setTextField method
```

My Entire GamePane Class:

```
    /**
     * This method adds objects to the pane, controls all animations for adding     and
     * moving enemies, adding and moving shots, and checking for collisions.
     * NOTE:  All methods for winning the game, losing the game, and such are to     be
     * implemented in future versions ;)
     */
    package StarshipBattleDestiny;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.util.Duration;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    class GamePane extends Pane {

    private Timeline animation;
    ArrayList<LargeEnemy> largeList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<SmallEnemy> smallList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Shot> shotList = new ArrayList<>(1);
    static double GAME_WIDTH = 1000;
    static double GAME_HEIGHT = 650;
    public static int gameOverCounter = 0;
    public static int playerPointCounter = 0;
    int addToPlayerScore;
    int addToMisses;
    public static Launcher launcher;
    Rectangle topOfGame;
    static String playerName;

    /**
     * This constructor for the GamePane calls the method that adds the
     * launcher, calls the method that adds the invisible object for the top of
     * the game, and houses the animations that control when a new enemy is
     * added, the rate that each SmallEnemy is moved, the rate that each
     * LargeEnemy is moved, the rate that each Shot is moved, and how often the
     * game will check for a collision.
     */
    public GamePane() {
        //Adds a launcher
        addLauncher();
        addTopOfGame();

        //Animation to call new enemies every 10 seconds.
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), e -> addEnemy()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();

        //Animation to move SmallEnemies
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5), e -> moveSmallEnemy()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();

        //Animation to move Large Enemies
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(8), e -> moveLargeEnemy()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();

        //Animation to move Shots
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> moveShot()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();

        this.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:purpleSpaceBackground.jpeg\");-fx-background-size: cover");
    } //End GamePane Constructor

    /**
     * This method adds a JOptionPane window informing the player of the
     * instructions of how to play the game.
     */
    public static void playerInstructionsPane() {
        playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name:");
        String blankName = "";
        String spaceName = " ";

        while (playerName.equalsIgnoreCase(blankName)) {
            playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You cannot leave your name blank.\n"
                    + "Please enter your name:");
        }
        while (playerName.equalsIgnoreCase(spaceName)) {
            playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("A space is not a valid name.\n"
                    + "Please enter your name:");
        }
        while (playerName.length() < 3) {
            playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player's name must be 3 characters or more in length.\n"
                    + "Please enter your name:");
        }

        String playerInstructionsMsg = "You are the captain of the Starship Destiny at the bottom of the screen.\n"
                + "Fire your Forward Guns at the enemy ships above you with the Space Bar.\n"
                + "The larger Asgard Ships are worth 10 points, while the smaller Kino Drones are worth twice that at 20 points.\n"
                + "It takes 500 points to win but only 10 misses to lose.\n\n"
                + "Winning the game earns you the coordinates to your enemy's base.\n\n"
                + "You can press the P button at any time to either surrender or show your enemies mercy.\n"
                + "This will also save your score and add it to the high scores, assuming it is one.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Good Luck!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerInstructionsMsg, "How To Play", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } //end playerInstructionsPane method

    /**
     * When this method is called it begins playing the animations.
     */
    public void play() {
        animation.play();
    } //End play method

    /**
     * When this method is called it stops playing the animations.
     */
    public void stop() {
        animation.stop();
    } //End stop method

    /**
     * When this method is called it pauses the animations that are playing.
     */
    public void pause() {
        animation.pause();
    } //End pause method

    /**
     * This method adds an invisible rectangle to the top that ends the game
     * when it is hit 10 times... (aka: when the player misses 10 times).
     */
    public void addTopOfGame() {
        topOfGame = new Rectangle(); //Set slightly above game view so shot will be offscreen before it dissapears.
        topOfGame.setX(0);
        topOfGame.setY(0);
        topOfGame.setHeight(10);
        topOfGame.setWidth(1000);
        topOfGame.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        this.getChildren().add(topOfGame);
        addToMisses = 1;
    } //End addTopOfGame methpd

    /**
     * This method adds a new Launcher to the pane.
     */
    public void addLauncher() {
        launcher = new Launcher();
        launcher.setWidth(70);
        launcher.setHeight(103);
        launcher.setX((GAME_WIDTH * 0.5) - (launcher.getWidth() * 0.5) + 10);
        launcher.setY(GAME_HEIGHT - 100);
        this.getChildren().add(launcher);
    } //End addLauncher method

    /**
     * This method adds new enemies. It has a random variable that generates a
     * number between 0 and 100. If this random variable is less than 60 a new
     * LargeEnemy is created and added to the pane, and if the random variable
     * is higher than 60 it crates a new SmallEnemy and adds it to the pane.
     * This means that there is a 60% chance of a new LargeEnemy being created
     * and a 40% chance of a new SmallEnemy being created.
     */
    public void addEnemy() {
        int random = (int) (0 + Math.random() * 100);
        if (random < 60) { //60:40 chance LargeEnemy:SmallEnemy
            addToPlayerScore = 10;
            LargeEnemy newLargeEnemy = new LargeEnemy();
            newLargeEnemy.setWidth(182);
            newLargeEnemy.setHeight(102);
            newLargeEnemy.setX(0);
            newLargeEnemy.setY(60 + Math.random() * 200);
            newLargeEnemy.setVisible(true);
            largeList.add(newLargeEnemy);
            this.getChildren().add(newLargeEnemy);
            //countdownToLargeCollisionCheck();
        } //End boolean if statement to add a newLargeEnemy
        else {
            addToPlayerScore = 20;
            SmallEnemy newSmallEnemy = new SmallEnemy();
            newSmallEnemy.setX(0);
            newSmallEnemy.setY(60 + Math.random() * 250);
            newSmallEnemy.setWidth(60);
            newSmallEnemy.setHeight(60);
            newSmallEnemy.setVisible(true);
            smallList.add(newSmallEnemy);
            this.getChildren().add(newSmallEnemy);
            //countdownToSmallCollisionCheck();
        } //End boolean else statemet to add a newSmallEnemy
    } //End addEnemy method

    /**
     * This method adds a new Shot to the screen. It is called whenever the
     * player hits the Space Bar.
     */
    public void fire() {
        if (shotList.isEmpty()) {
            Shot newShot = new Shot();
            newShot.setX(GAME_WIDTH * 0.5);
            newShot.setY(launcher.getY() - launcher.getHeight() - 30);
            newShot.setWidth(18);
            newShot.setHeight(134);
            newShot.setVisible(true);
            shotList.add(newShot);
            this.getChildren().add(newShot);
        }
        else {
            //Don't add a new shot.
        }
    } //End fire method

    /**
     * This method sets how much each SmallEnemy will be moved each time the
     * animation timer calls the method, as well as removing the SmallEnemy if
     * it's x-axis value is greater than or equal to the width of the game + the
     * width of a SmallEnemy.
     */
    public void moveSmallEnemy() {
        for (int i = 0; i < smallList.size(); i++) {
            SmallEnemy moveSmall = smallList.get(i);
            double x = moveSmall.getX();
            double smallDX = 1;
            double removeSmall = GAME_WIDTH + moveSmall.getWidth();
            if (x >= removeSmall) {
                smallList.remove(i);
            } //end boolean if statement to change direction
            x += smallDX;
            moveSmall.setX(x);
        } //end for loop
    } //End moveSmallEnemy method

    /**
     * This method sets how much each LargeEnemy will be moved each time the
     * animation timer calls the method, as well as removing the LargeEnemy if
     * it's x-axis value is greater than or equal to the width of the game + the
     * width of a LargeEnemy.
     */
    public void moveLargeEnemy() {
        for (int i = 0; i < largeList.size(); i++) {
            LargeEnemy moveLarge = largeList.get(i);
            double x = moveLarge.getX();
            double largeDX = 1;
            double removeLarge = GAME_WIDTH + moveLarge.getWidth();
            if (x >= removeLarge) {
                largeList.remove(i);
            } //end boolean if statement to change direction
            x += largeDX;
            moveLarge.setX(x);
        } //end for loop
    } //End moveLargeEnemy method

    /**
     * This method sets how much each Shot will be moved each time the animation
     * timer calls the method.
     */
    public void moveShot() {
        if (shotList.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < shotList.size(); i++) {
            Shot shot = shotList.get(i);
            double y = shot.getY();
            double dy = 0.21;
            y -= dy;
            shot.setY(y);
        } //End for loop
        collisionCheckTimeline();
    } //End moveShot method

    /**
     * When this method is called it runs the animations to check for collisions
     * with each SmallEnemy, each LargeEnemy, and with the invisible object at
     * the top of the game.
     */
    public void collisionCheckTimeline() {
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> checkCollisionSmall()));
        animation.setCycleCount(1);
        animation.play();   

        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> checkCollisionLarge()));
        animation.setCycleCount(1);
        animation.play();

        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> checkTopCollision()));
        animation.setCycleCount(1);
        animation.play();
    } //End smallCollisionTimeline method

    /**
     * This method checks for collisions with each SmallEnemy.
     */
    public void checkCollisionSmall() {
        //This segment of code checks for collisions with each SmallEnemy.
        for (int i = 0; i < shotList.size(); i++) {
            Shot tempShot = shotList.get(i);
            tempShot.setVisible(true);
            for (int j = 0; j < smallList.size(); j++) {
                SmallEnemy tempSmall = smallList.get(i);
                tempSmall.setVisible(true);
                if (tempShot.isVisible() && tempSmall.isVisible()) {
                    if (tempShot.getBoundsInLocal().intersects(tempSmall.getBoundsInLocal())) {
                        tempShot.setVisible(false);
                        tempSmall.setVisible(false);
                        smallList.remove(j);
                        shotList.remove(i);
                        setScore();
                    } //End inner boolean if statement
                } //End of outer boolean if statement
            } //End inner for loop
        } //End outer for loop
    } //End checkCollisionSmall method

    /**
     * This method checks for collisions with each LargeEnemy.
     */
    public void checkCollisionLarge() {
        //This segment of code checks for collisions with each LargeEnemy.
        for (int i = 0; i < shotList.size(); i++) {
            Shot tempShot = shotList.get(i);
            tempShot.setVisible(true);
            for (int j = 0; j < largeList.size(); j++) {
                LargeEnemy tempLarge = largeList.get(j);
                tempLarge.setVisible(true);
                if (tempShot.isVisible() && tempLarge.isVisible()) {
                    if (tempShot.getBoundsInParent().intersects(tempLarge.getBoundsInParent())) {
                        tempShot.setVisible(false);
                        tempLarge.setVisible(false);
                        largeList.remove(j);
                        shotList.remove(i);
                        setScore();
                    } //End inner boolean if statement
                } //End outer boolean if statement
            } //End inner for loop
        } //End outer for loop
    } //End checkCollisionLarge method

    /**
     * This method checks for a collision with the invisible rectangle at the 
     * top of the screen.
     */
    public void checkTopCollision() {        
        //This segment of code checks for collisions with the invisible topOfGame Rectangle object.
        for (int i = 0; i < shotList.size(); i++) {
            Shot tempShot = shotList.get(i);
            tempShot.setVisible(true);
            if (tempShot.isVisible() && topOfGame.isVisible()) {
                if (tempShot.getBoundsInParent().intersects(topOfGame.getBoundsInParent())) {
                    tempShot.setVisible(false);
                    shotList.remove(i);
                    setMisses();
                } //end inner boolean if statement
            } //end outer boolean if statement
        } //end for loop
    } //End checkTopCollision method

    /**
     * This method updates the counter for the player's points.
     */
    public void setScore() {
        //int pointsToWin = 500;
        playerPointCounter += addToPlayerScore;
        System.out.println("Score updated:  " + playerPointCounter);
        setTextField();
        //If the player gets a point amount within the given range the winGame and stop method are called.
        if (playerPointCounter > 499 && playerPointCounter < 511) { 
            winGame();
            stop();
        }
    } //End setScore method

    /**
     * This method updates the counter for the player's misses.
     */
    public void setMisses() {
        int missesToLose = 10;
        gameOverCounter += addToMisses;
        System.out.println("Misses Updated:  " + gameOverCounter);
        setTextField();
        //If the player gets the number of points designated then the loseGame method is called.
        if (gameOverCounter == missesToLose) {
            loseGame();
        }
        while(gameOverCounter == missesToLose) {
            stop();
        }
    } //End setMisses method

    /**
     * This method updates the Text object with the new score information, removes
     * the old TextField from the Pane, and adds the new Text object with the
     * updated score to the pane. It is called every time a collision is
     * detected and the player's score counter or miss counter is updated.
     */
    public void setTextField() {
        Text showScore = new Text("Score:  " + String.valueOf(playerPointCounter)
            + "\nMisses:  " + String.valueOf(gameOverCounter));
        showScore.setLayoutX(25);
        showScore.setLayoutY(35);
        showScore.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        //Font family, weight, font size
        showScore.setFont(Font.font("Baskerville Old Face", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        this.getChildren().remove(showScore);
        this.getChildren().add(showScore);
    } //End setTextField method

    /**
     * This method determines if the player loses the game. The player loses the
     * game when they miss a target 10 times. When the game is lost a
     * JOptionPane window displays telling them the game is over and how many
     * points they had when they lost. This method also stops all animations.
     */
    public static void loseGame() {    
        String playerLosesMsg = "You Missed 10 times and Lost!\n\n"
            + "Your Score:  " + playerPointCounter;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerLosesMsg, "Game Over!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        mainScoreControl();
        System.exit(10);
    } //End loseGame method

    /**
     * This method determines if the player wins the game. The player wins the
     * game when they earn 500 points. When the game is won a JOptionPane
     * window displays telling them they won the game, how many points they
     * had at the end, how many misses they had, and the coordinates for the
     * final location.
     */
    public static void winGame() {
        final String FINAL_COORDS = "N 39 00.000  W 084 00.000";
        String playerWinsMsg = "You Win!\n\n"
            + "Your Score:  " + playerPointCounter + "\n"
            + "Misses:  " + gameOverCounter + "\n\n"
            + "Final Coordinates for GC00000:\n"
            + FINAL_COORDS;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, playerWinsMsg, "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        //mainScoreControl(); REMOVED
    } //End winGame method

    /**
     * When the player presses the "P" button this method is called.
     * It displays one of two messages based on how many points the player has
     * at the time it is pressed.  One message the player accepts their loss and
     * for the other the game accepts their loss.  Either way the player's
     * point total and total number of misses are displayed and the
     * mainScoreControl method is called.
     */
    public static void endGame() {
        if (playerPointCounter <= 499) {
            String surrenderMsg = "Your surrender has been accepted, Captain!\n\n"
            + "Your Score:  " + playerPointCounter + "\n"
            + "Misses:  " + gameOverCounter;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, surrenderMsg, "Surrender Accepted", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            String endGameMsg = "We accept our defeat... for now!\n\n"
            + "Your Score:  " + playerPointCounter + "\n"
            + "Misses:  " + gameOverCounter;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, endGameMsg, "Game Over!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }  
        mainScoreControl();
        //System.exit(1);
    } //End endGame method

    /**
     * This method creates a new instance of HighScoreManager, adds the player's
     * score to the ArrayList of high scores in the HSM Class via its addScore
     * method, and outputs that information in a JOptionPane window.
     */
    public static void mainScoreControl() {
        HighScoreManager highScoreManager = new HighScoreManager();
        highScoreManager.addScore(playerName,playerPointCounter);
        System.out.print(highScoreManager.getHighscoreString());

        String highScoreMsg = highScoreManager.getHighscoreStringMsg();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, highScoreMsg, "High Scores", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    } //End mainScoreControl method

    /**
     * Called when Control-Alt-P is pressed so I can view the high scores without accidentally effecting anything.
     */
    public static void showHighScores() {
        HighScoreManager highScoreManager = new HighScoreManager();
        String highScoreMsg = highScoreManager.getHighscoreStringMsg();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, highScoreMsg, "High Scores", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    } //End showHighScores method

    public static void keyTest() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        String thing = cacheManager.getCoordinateString();
        System.out.println(thing);
    }

    public static void mainCacheControl() {     
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();

        String newGcCode;
        String newCoordinates;
        String newAdminPassword;

        String userEnteredPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Your Admin Password:  ");

        String adminPassword = cacheManager.getAdminPasswordString();
        if (userEnteredPassword.equals(adminPassword)) {
            newGcCode = changeGcCode();
            newCoordinates = changeCoordinates();   
            newAdminPassword = changeAdminPassword();
            cacheManager.addCacheInfo(newAdminPassword, newGcCode, newCoordinates);

            String newCacheInfoMsg = "Your new GC Code is:  " + newGcCode + "\n" +
                "Your new Coordinates are:  " + newCoordinates + "\n" +
                "Your new Admin Password is:  " + newAdminPassword;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newCacheInfoMsg, "[ADMIN] Review New Cache Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            String incorrectAdminPasswordMsg = "You incorrectly entered the Admin Password.  Terminating Program.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrectAdminPasswordMsg, "Incorrect Admin Password Entered", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(666);
        }

        System.exit(1);
    } //End mainScoreControl method

    public static String changeGcCode() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        String gcCode;
        String gcChangeMsg = "Would you like to change the GC Code?";

        int changeGcCode = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, gcChangeMsg, "[ADMIN] GC Code Options", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (changeGcCode == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            gcCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the New GC Code:  ");
        }
        else {
            if (cacheManager.isListEmpty() == false) {
                gcCode = cacheManager.getCacheGcCodeString();
            }
            else {
                CacheInfo cacheInfo = new CacheInfo();
                gcCode = cacheInfo.getGcCode();
            }
        }
        return gcCode;
    } //End changeGcCode method

    public static String changeCoordinates() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        String finalCoordinates;
        String coordChangeMsg = "Would you like to change the Coordinates?";

        int changeCoords = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, coordChangeMsg, "[ADMIN] Coordinate Options", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
        if (changeCoords == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            finalCoordinates = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the New Coordinates:  ");
        }
        else {
            if (cacheManager.isListEmpty() == false) {
                finalCoordinates = cacheManager.getCoordinateString();
            }
            else {
                CacheInfo cacheInfo = new CacheInfo();
                finalCoordinates = cacheInfo.getFinalCoordinates();
            }
        }
        return finalCoordinates;
    } //End changeCoordinates method

    public static String changeAdminPassword() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        String adminPassword;
        String coordChangeMsg = "Would you like to change the Admin Password?";

        int changeAdminPassword = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, coordChangeMsg, "[ADMIN] Admin Password Options", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
        if (changeAdminPassword == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            adminPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the New Admin Password:  ");
        }
        else {
            if (cacheManager.isListEmpty() == false) {
                adminPassword = cacheManager.getAdminPasswordString();
            }
            else {
                CacheInfo cacheInfo = new CacheInfo();
                adminPassword = cacheInfo.getAdminPassword();
            }
        }
        return adminPassword;
    }


} //End of GamePane Class
```

Answer (score 1):

To show what is the problem, let's put it more simple:

```
public void setTextField() {
    Text showScore = new Text("Score:  "+String.valueOf(playerPointCounter));
    this.getChildren().remove(showScore);
    this.getChildren().add(showScore);
}
```

The problem is this: `this.getChildren().remove(showScore);` tries to remove the new `showScore` object you have just created, which is not even on the pane, it is not removing previous `Text` nodes, and you are adding a new instance with every call.

One first solution will be deleting all `Text` instances found:

```
public void setTextField() {
    Text showScore = new Text("Score:  "+String.valueOf(playerPointCounter));
    this.getChildren().removeIf(Text.class::isInstance);
    this.getChildren().add(showScore);
}
```

Note `removeIf` requires Java 8. Since this is not the best solution I won't go into a Java 7 version. Also it will delete all other possible texts, so maybe you could set an `id` to the text and delete the nodes with that id.

Second option: create a global `Text` node in your class:

```
final Text showScore;
public GamePane() {
    ...
    showScore=new Text();
    this.getChildren().add(showScore);
}
```

and now simple update it's text property:

```
public void setTextField() {
    showScore.setText("Score:  " + String.valueOf(playerPointCounter)
        + "\nMisses:  " + String.valueOf(gameOverCounter));
    showScore.setLayoutX(25);
    showScore.setLayoutY(35);
    showScore.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    //Font family, weight, font size
    showScore.setFont(Font.font("Baskerville Old Face", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
}
```

Note that every time you call `setTextfield()` you are layouting the control, so this could be moved to the constructor.

Third option: create the node, and use some properties bounded to it. Call `setTextField()` only once, to create the binding and layout the node. And then, you just need to increment the counters when required (`incrementPointCounter()` for instance):

```
private final Text showScore=new Text();
private final IntegerProperty playerPointCounter=new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final IntegerProperty gameOverCounter=new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public void setTextField() {
    showScore.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("Score:  ")
                      .concat(playerPointCounter.asString())
        .concat("\nMisses:  ").concat(gameOverCounter.asString()));

    showScore.setLayoutX(25);
    showScore.setLayoutY(35);
    showScore.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    //Font family, weight, font size
    showScore.setFont(Font.font("Baskerville Old Face", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
    this.getChildren().add(showScore);
}

public void incrementPointCounter(){
    playerPointCounter.set(playerPointCounter.get()+1);
}
```